# Cómo introducir certificado electrónico para envío de facturas emitidas proyecto SII (Suministro Inmediato de Información)

Tags: java, webservice, aeat-sii

Estoy intentando hacer en envió de pruebas de facturas emitidas de pruebas de la AEAT, pero no veo la manera de introducir el certificado electrónico en el envió para poder tener la autentifican.

Espero que me podáis ayudar. Gracias

Siempre obtengo este mensaje de vuelta del web service

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server
>   sent HTTP status code 200: OK

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas emitidas = new SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas();


    PF pf = new PF(false);
    Factura factura = pf.getFacturaBean().read(3);
    Recurso recurso = pf.getRecursoBean().read(1);
    Collection<Iva> tiposIva = pf.getIvaBean().readAll();
    CabeceraSii cabeceraSii = new CabeceraSii();
    PersonaFisicaJuridicaESType persona = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaESType();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    //CABECERA
    cabeceraSii.setIDVersionSii("0.6");
    cabeceraSii.setTipoComunicacion(ClaveTipoComunicacionType.A_0);
    persona.setNombreRazon(recurso.getEmpresa());
    persona.setNIF(recurso.getCif());
    cabeceraSii.setTitular(persona);
    //FIN CABECERA

    //LISTA FACTURAS EMITIDAS
    ArrayList<LRfacturasEmitidasType> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    //FACTURA EMITIDA
    LRfacturasEmitidasType facturaEmitida = new LRfacturasEmitidasType();

    //Periodo Impositivo
    RegistroSii.PeriodoImpositivo pe = new RegistroSii.PeriodoImpositivo();

   pe.setEjercicio(factura.getIdNumeroFactura()
   .getIdEjercicio().getEjercicio());
    c.setTime(factura.getFechaFactura());
    Integer mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    String mesStr = mes.toString();
    if (mesStr.length() == 1)
    {
        mesStr = "0" + mesStr;
    }
    pe.setPeriodo(mesStr);
    facturaEmitida.setPeriodoImpositivo(pe);
    //FIN Periodo Impositivo

    //IDFactura
    IDFacturaExpedidaType idFa = new IDFacturaExpedidaType();
    IDFacturaExpedidaType.IDEmisorFactura idEmisor = new IDFacturaExpedidaType.IDEmisorFactura();

    idEmisor.setNIF(factura.getIdCliente().getCifNif());
    idFa.setIDEmisorFactura(idEmisor);
    idFa.setNumSerieFacturaEmisor(factura.toString());
    idFa.setFechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor(formatter.format(factura.getFechaFactura()));
    facturaEmitida.setIDFactura(idFa);
    //FIN IDFactura

    //FacturaExpedida
    FacturaExpedidaType facturaExpedidaType = new FacturaExpedidaType();
    facturaExpedidaType.setTipoFactura(ClaveTipoFacturaType.F_1);
    if (factura.getIdCliente().getTipoNacionalidadCliente().equals(1) || factura.getIdCliente().getTipoNacionalidadCliente().equals(3))
    {
        facturaExpedidaType.setClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia("01");
    }
    else if (factura.getIdCliente().getTipoNacionalidadCliente().equals(2) || factura.getIdCliente().getTipoNacionalidadCliente().equals(4))
    {
        facturaExpedidaType.setClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia("02");
    }
    Double importeTotal;
    if (factura.getIdCliente().getTipoNacionalidadCliente().equals(1))
    {
        importeTotal = factura.getTotalFacturaPorSumaLineas();
    }
    else
    {
        importeTotal = factura.getBaseFacturaPorSumaLineas();
    }
    importeTotal = getDoubleTwoDecimals(importeTotal);
    facturaExpedidaType.setImporteTotal(importeTotal.toString());
    facturaExpedidaType.setDescripcionOperacion("venta de productos");
    PersonaFisicaJuridicaType contraparte = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaType();
    contraparte.setNIF(factura.getIdCliente().getCifNif());
    contraparte.setNombreRazon(factura.getIdCliente().getNombre());
    facturaExpedidaType.setContraparte(contraparte);

    DesgloseIVA desgloseIva = new DesgloseIVA();
    ArrayList<DetalleIVAEmitidaType> detallesIva = new ArrayList<>();
    DetalleIVAEmitidaType detalleIva;
    for (Iva idIva : tiposIva)
    {
        Double iva = 0.0, recargo = 0.0, base = 0.0;
        for (LineaFactura linea : factura.getLineas())
        {
            if (idIva.equals(linea.getIdIva()))
            {
                base += linea.getBase();
                if (factura.getIdCliente().getTipoNacionalidadCliente().equals(1))
                {
                    iva += linea.getIva();
                    if (factura.getRecargo() && linea.getRecargo() > 0)
                    {
                        recargo += linea.getRecargo();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (base != 0.0)
        {
            detalleIva = new DetalleIVAEmitidaType();
            detalleIva.setBaseImponible(getDoubleTwoDecimals(base).toString());
            detalleIva.setTipoImpositivo(idIva.getValor().toString());
            detalleIva.setCuotaRepercutida(getDoubleTwoDecimals(iva).toString());
            if (recargo > 0)
            {
                detalleIva.setTipoRecargoEquivalencia(idIva.getRecargo().toString());
                detalleIva.setCuotaRepercutida(getDoubleTwoDecimals(recargo).toString());
            }
            desgloseIva.getDetalleIVA().add(detalleIva);
        }
    }

    NoExenta noExtenta = new NoExenta();
    noExtenta.setDesgloseIVA(desgloseIva);
    noExtenta.setTipoNoExenta(TipoOperacionSujetaNoExentaType.S_1);
    SujetaType sujetaType = new SujetaType();
    sujetaType.setNoExenta(noExtenta);
    TipoSinDesgloseType desgloseFactura = new TipoSinDesgloseType();
    desgloseFactura.setSujeta(sujetaType);
    FacturaExpedidaType.TipoDesglose tipoDesglose = new FacturaExpedidaType.TipoDesglose();
    tipoDesglose.setDesgloseFactura(desgloseFactura);
    facturaExpedidaType.setTipoDesglose(tipoDesglose);

    //FIN FacturaExpedida
    lista.add(facturaEmitida);

    // DATOS PRESENTACION
    DatosPresentacionType datosPresentacion = new DatosPresentacionType();
    datosPresentacion.setNIFPresentador(recurso.getEmpresa());
    datosPresentacion.setTimestampPresentacion(formatter2.format(new Date()));

    //ESTADO ENVIO
    EstadoEnvioType estadoEnvio = EstadoEnvioType.CORRECTO;

    // RESPUESTA LINEA
    List<RespuestaExpedidaType> respuestasExpedidaType = new ArrayList<>();

   emitidas.setCabecera(cabeceraSii);
   emitidas.getRegistroLRFacturasEmitidas().addAll(lista);


    RespuestaLRFEmitidasType emitidasType = suministroLRFacturasEmitidas(emitidas);

   int a = 8;
}

private static RespuestaLRFEmitidasType suministroLRFacturasEmitidas(SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas emitidas)
{
    try
    {

        https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService service = new https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiService();
        https.www2_agenciatributaria_gob_es.static_files.common.internet.dep.aplicaciones.es.aeat.ssii.fact.ws.suministrofactemitidas.SiiSOAP port = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
        RespuestaLRFEmitidasType emitidasType = port.suministroLRFacturasEmitidas(emitidas);
        return emitidasType;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

He econtrado la respuesta, os comento

1.Consumir el WS de manera normal desde el Netbeans o Eclipse (http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_06/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl)

2.Descargar liberias de http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cxf/3.1.11/apache-cxf-3.1.11.zip y añadirlas al proyecto.

3.En el almacen de certificados de windows solo debeis tener instalado el que vais a usar, porque si existe mas de uno se hace un lio.

3. Este seria el codigo para la llamada al WS.
   private static void  suministroLRFacturasEmitidas(List lista ,Holder cabecera, Holder csv, Holder datosPresentacion, Holder estadoEnvio, Holder> respuestaLinea) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchProviderException
   {
       KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
       keyStore.load(null, null);

   ```
   KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
   kmf.init(keyStore, null);

   TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
   tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLS");
   tlsParams.setKeyManagers(kmf.getKeyManagers());

   SiiService service = new SiiService();
   SiiSOAP soap = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
   ((HTTPConduit)ClientProxy.getClient(soap).getConduit()).setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
   soap.suministroLRFacturasEmitidas(cabecera, lista, csv, datosPresentacion, estadoEnvio, respuestaLinea);
   ```

   }